# What is the right measure for the upper half-plane?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, hyperbolic-geometry

I think my question depends on the context of the problem so let me give you some background. I want to measure subsets of $\{(x,y)|~y>0, x\in \mathbb{R}\}$. I'm not involved with differential geometry. So what is the right measure for the upper halfplane. If one identifies it with the hyperbolic plane I saw that one possibility is $\frac{1}{y^2}dxdy$ but on the other hand this is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so with the Lebesgue measure we can also measure subsets.

The motivation behind it is as follows. We want to integrate a function on some subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and use cylindrical coordinates, assume there is no dependence on the angle. Then the integral becomes and integral on some subset of the upper halfplane. For me, it seems natural to measure things with the Lebesgue measure.

Is there a "natural" way to decide which measure to use?

Comment: It all depends on the properties you want this measure to have.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Are there any advantages for using $\frac{1}{y^2}dxdy$ and if so what are they?

Comment: Invariance under hyperbolic isometries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something - But if you want the value of the integral to be meaningful with respect to your original problem, you don't get to choose the measure.

If you have a function, given in Euclidean coordinates, it is likely this function is meaningful, as a measurable function, with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

If you want to integrate under different coordinates, that's fine as well - you have to use the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) to calculate the "fine" you have to pay.

This "fine" is actually the Lebesgue measure, given in polar coordinates. If we look at it from a Differential-Geometric point of view, you've just described the same [volume form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form) under different coordinates.

Comment: Exactly that is also why I thought the Lebesgue measure should be the right choice! The modulus of the Jacobian gives $r$. I think this is also what was irritating me because I thought the Jacobian has to be pushed over to the measure and then I started pondering about the right measure...

Comment: For me, it's helpful to think of it the following way. Changing the measure corresponds to "Change the density of the domain of integration". Changing the coordinates is "Change the way the domain of integration is represented in our map". Since our map deforms the domain of integration, the two can be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the most natural measure is proportional to ${dxdy\over y^2}$. This measure is invariant by the isometries of ${\bf H}$, just as the Lebesgue measure on the euclidean plane ${\bf R}^2$ is invariant by the transformations of the plane that preserves the norm.

The isometries of ${\bf H}$ that preserve the orientation are the homographies $z \mapsto {az+b \over cz+d}$ with $ad-bc = 1$ and $a,b,c,d \in {\bf R}$. You can check that these transformations preserve the measure $${dx\wedge dy\over y^2} = {i \  dz \wedge d\bar{z} \over 2 Im(z)^2}.$$